# How can I do it Erc20 Token Address Subscription

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20

API listening to the transaction at the router address in the code below In addition, can I add the any token address on this router address for subscription?

```
 wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    let txChecker = new TransactionChecker(process.env.WEB_SOCKET_PROVIDER_URL, process.env.HTTP_PROVIDER_URL, '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D');
    txChecker.subscribe('pendingTransactions');
    txChecker.watchTransactions(ws);
});
```

Comment: What is `TransactionChecker`? Where is it from?

Comment: subscribe(topic) {
        this.subscription = this.web3ws.eth.subscribe(topic, (err, res) => {
            if (err)
                console.error(err);
        })

Comment: module.exports = TransactionChecker

Comment: Please include a minimal self contained example. It is not possible to test when the whole code is missing.

Comment: can I send you email file full code ? You will reply here again. Can you give me your email address?

Comment: It is better to add the necessary to the question. In general detecting token transfers is easy, you only have to listen for `Transfer` events. For ethers transfer you have to inspect internal transactions.